# Bundle install throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, bundler

I am getting the following error when I try to run `bundle install`

```
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3tutorial/cache/turbolinks-2.1.0.gem. It may be corrupted.

An error occurred while installing turbolinks (2.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install turbolinks -v '2.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Even if in install the above said gem and rub `bundle install` it throws a similar error and asks me to make sure an another gem is installed and this goes on and on.
I am using Rails 4.0.2 and ruby 1.9.3p484.

Comment: Try adding `gem 'turbolinks'` to your _gemfile_ and then use `bundle install`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the file cache got corrupted. Try:

```
bundle install --no-cache
```

If this does not work, delete the cache directory and try again:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3tutorial/cache
bundle install
```

Comment: Hey Sparkplug, feedback won't hurt ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem with the `bcrypt` gem

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...

Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /data/code/mdweb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/cache/bcrypt-3.1.7.gem. It may be
 corrupted.
An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

The `/data/code/mdweb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/cache/bcrypt-3.1.7.gem` file was 0 bytes; removing this file or using the `--no-cache` option didn't help.

Using `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.7'` *did* work, so I copied `~/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/cache/bcrypt-3.1.7.gem` to `/data/code/mdweb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/cache/bcrypt-3.1.7.gem` and that allowed me to continue. You could also fetch the `.gem` file from http://rubygems.org if you can't find it on your system.

I suspect there's some sort of connection issue with `bundler` (but not with `gem` for some reason); I suspect DNS since there's an unusual long wait before I get an error, but didn't investigate further.

Comment: Wow, yeah, I just ran into this and manually downloading the .gem file from rubygems.org did the trick (there's a link in the sidebar called "download"). Wow, that's a bad bug...